# How can I get the count of consecutive positive number in each column in 2 dimensional df in python/ Padas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
      X     y
a   1.0  -1.0
b  -2.0   2.0
c   3.0  -3.0
d   2.1   4.0

Output: 
       x     y
  a   1.0  -1.0
  b  -2.0   2.0
  c   3.0  -3.0
  d   2.1   4.0
Count 2     1
```

As on the first column, the count is reset to 0 on row b because of -2. The result needs to be a df with the count appended at last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us use `cumsum` def your function

```
def yourfun(x) : 
       return x[x.ge(0)].groupby(x.lt(0).cumsum()).size().iloc[-1]
df.loc['Count'] = df.apply(yourfun)
df
Out[62]: 
         X    y
a      1.0 -1.0
b     -2.0  2.0
c      3.0 -3.0
d      2.1  4.0
Count  2.0  1.0
```

Comment: Hi Beny, Thank you for the response. Actually with the code I am getting total number of +VE number count. I want the total count of +Ve number from last. For example on the x column, it needs to give count as 2 not as the last consecutive +ve number are 3 and 2.

Comment: @SudeepKafle change the max to .iloc[-1]

Comment: Thank you so much BENY. That works perfectly.

Comment: Hi BENY Quick question, if I want to treat 0 as -ve number and don't what should I do? when the -ve number comes I want to reset the count to 0.

Comment: @SudeepKafle then you can change ge to gt and lt to le ~, gt = greater , ge : greate and equal ~

Comment: Clever idea to group on `x.lt(0).cumsum()`! I believe the `numpy` version I described has an edge in speed however (roughly 14x in my benchmarks).

Answer (score 0):

There is a pure `numpy` way without `groupby` (in other words: likely to be very fast). It also counts runs of strictly positive values (excluding 0):

```py
def countpos(x):
    return np.diff(np.where(np.hstack((-1, x, -1)) <= 0)[0]).max() - 1

df.loc['Count'] = df.apply(countpos)
```

Result:

```py
>>> df
         X    y
a      1.0 -1.0
b     -2.0  2.0
c      3.0 -3.0
d      2.1  4.0
Count  2.0  1.0
```

**Explanation**

The `np.where()` looks for the indices of all non-positive values. For example:

```py
>>> np.where(np.array([0,0,1,1,0,0,1]) <= 0)
(array([0, 1, 4, 5]),)
```

We bracked the actual values with `-1` on both sides, to force `np.where()` to tell us about those indices too. Then, take the `diff`, `max`, et voila: the maximum length of runs of strictly positive numbers.

**Speed**

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=(10000,100)))

a = %timeit -o df.apply(countpos)
14.3 ms ± 11.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

```
df.loc['count'] =  df.lt(0).diff().ne(0).cumsum().stack().groupby(level=1).value_counts().groupby(level=0).max()
```

or

```
d = df.gt(0).cumsum()

pd.concat([df,d.sub(d.where(df.lt(0)).ffill().fillna(0)).max().to_frame('Count').T])
```

Output:

```
         X    y
a      1.0 -1.0
b     -2.0  2.0
c      3.0 -3.0
d      2.1  4.0
Count  2.0  1.0
```